# SPQuery always returns values

Tags: caml-query, spquery

I am trying to check a list for related values but for some reason every item in the list is returned each time. I have seen this issue before and for me its always meant a bad CAML string but I have not been able to figgure out what is wrong.

Table contains two extra fields:

```
 FieldName | Type
 ---------------------------
    'List'        | GUID
    'URL'         | URL
```

Current Query:

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
 String myID=web.Lists["myList"].ID.ToString();
 String myUrl = web.Url;

 SPQuery MyQuery = new SPQuery();
 MyQuery.Query= "
    <Where>
           <And>
                   <Contains>
                         <FieldRef Name='List'/>
                         <Value Type='String'>"+myID+"</Value>
                  </Contains>
                <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='URL'/>
                        <Value Type='URL'>"+myUrl+"</Value>
                </Eq>
          </And>
     </Where>";

      SPListItemCollection results = web.Lists["sourceList"].GetItems(MyQuery);
```

I have also tried with  in place of  and Text in place of String.

- I do know the      (string)list.ID. is same format as my GUID Field which is why matching by string should work

Comment: returning all items on `GetItems()` is a common side-effect of the query being invalid. I'd check it in CAML Query Builder or similar and see if it does what you expect.

Comment: Have you tried `<Value Type="Text">` instead of with `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems fine to me,
I would suggest using a nice tool that will generate you a caml query so you can compare the results.
It's free and called [CamlDesigner](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/caml-designer/).

Try it.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your List field is of SPFieldType.Guid, then you should rather use strict comparison (`Eq`). Also I set Type attribute of Value Tag to **Guid**, but It is not nessesary:

```
<Eq>
  <FieldRef Name="List" />
  <Value Type="Guid">+myId+</Value>
</Eq>
```